# Difference between wi-fi router and usb modem devices

Tags: connection

Both usb and wifi routers are modes of connectivity. 
Is there any difference between the two devices? Is it correct to say both are same?

Comment: Ummm, really?  USB is wired and wifi is wireless.  They are not both wireless.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information.  However the answer says wifi can be used as a wired network as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the term USB modem refers to any type of  data/fax/voice modem device which can be connected to a computer using USB, the term more commonly describes a specific portable USB device that looks similar to a USB flash drive and can be as small as 100 x 35 x 23mm in physical size and weigh only around 25grams . These small portable USB fax modems do not require a power source and can be plugged into any USB port on your PC, notebook, or Macintosh computer and can also be disconnected from the computer without turning off the system. One end of the portable USB modem will have a USB interface, while the other end will have an RJ-11 port for connecting your phone line.
A wireless router is a device that performs the functions of a router and also includes the functions of a wireless access point. It is used to provide access to the Internet or a private computer network. It can function in a wired LAN (local area network), in a wireless-only LAN (WLAN), or in a mixed wired/wireless network, depending on the manufacturer and model.